# Why are these objects transparent everywhere?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, png

I am trying to export leaves and branches from **Illustrator**. I would like the area which is not branches and leaves to be transparent (*the white part in the image below*), and the area which is leaves and branches to be entirely opaque (*green part below*).

[image]

*＾ This is what one of the objects look like in the Illustrator window*

[image]

*＾ Here are the **Gradient** settings, both colors in the gradient are 100% opaque*

[image]

*＾ **Object**'s Opacity settings: It is set to opaque there too*

[image]

*＾ This is the **Appearance** panel, all seems fine there too...*

[image]

*＾ Here are my **Save for Web** settings (which allow me to have better control of the file format settings)*

[image]

*＾ But when I drag them into Photoshop (or any other app!), the leaves are transparent!*

***Why, oh why, cannot the produced file match the Object's transparency settings?***

Comment: What's inside the group in the Appearance Panel......... Put a colored rectangle behind the leaf.. see if it's transparent in AI. (I've never seen this happen if things actually are 100% opaque in AI)

Comment: [Ok, yeah, that's super weird...](https://imgur.com/a/999YoTC) - I think your suggestion is right, the group [is composed of two objects](https://imgur.com/a/pNBZwGc) who each have [70% opacity](https://imgur.com/a/y3aF3uX)!! How the hell does the Opacity of the group say "100%" instead of "70%" when I select the whole group - yet another bug in AI... Can you make your comment an answer?

Comment: Because object opacity is independent of group opacity. It's common, and opacity has always "stacked" (for lack of a better term). It's like setting a layer in Photoshop to 70% opacity, then putting it in a group.. you can then set the group to 10% opacity. Same thing in AI. It's merely the internal object information within a group isn't as readily visible in AI.

Comment: @Scott one might argue that it isn't a behavior that is consistent across graphical apps. Another approach would be to give the Group an Opacity value that is actually based on its contents (so for example object one is 50% opaque, object 2 is 100% opaque, therefore group value is 75%... thus pointing the user to what is going on more efficiently). Because you cannot make 100% "opaque" groups of objects with 0% opacity... it make no logical sense to call it "100% Opaque"

Comment: `:)` It's **is** consistent across all *Adobe* applications though. I find it very logical once you understand it. And really, anything other than this would mean you are *sacrificing* some edit ability. If I set a group to 100% opaque I *absolutely* do NOT then want objects inside that group to subsequently be set to 100% opaque as well. I want the *objects* to maintain their settings in all instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the `<Group>` in the **Appearance Panel** and ensure the objects *within the group* are *also* set to 100% opacity.

Opacity will "stack". Meaning Object opacity is *separate and independent* from Group opacity.

You can easily have 70% opaque objects inside a group which is set to 100% opaque... which results in a 70% opaque appearance. The Appearance Panel, by default, merely shows the Group opacity. You have to "delve deeper" into the appearance to see the object opacity setting(s). Yeah, it's kind of hidden. But the logic as to why the group reflects 100% Opacity, when the objects inside the group are *not* 100% opaque is sound logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - although we do not agree either on the definition of the word "Opacity" or "logic"  either something is 100% opaque - or it isn't.

Comment: Actually I think we do agree `:)` You simply aren't seeing the value in the independent object/group settings. If the Appearance panel laid out objects and groups the same way Photoshop lays out Layers and Layer Groups, it would all make perfect sense to you I think. `:)`

Comment: But if I group 10 objects and then set Stroke size to 10 px, all objects will be impacted, instead of the imaginary "Box" around them. However for transparency it's a different logic that applies? Either all objects grouped can be modified together or not...

Comment: Well if you add a stroke **to the group** then that stroke is applied to the **group** and **not** the objects inside the group. Changing it doesn't subsequently alter the stroke on objects *inside* the group. Opacity works exactly the same way. The *only* difference is you don't "add" opacity to groups, it's there by default at 100%. Whereas, by default, groups don't have a stroke.

Comment: -- rectangle with 8pt red stroke... circle with 4pt green stroke.. group them... add 1pt black stroke to group via appearance panel. *nothing* you do to the *group's black stoke* will alter the red and green strokes of it's internal objects. The MOST you could possibly do is *cover up* the internal strokes by a group stroke via appearance panel stacking. Opacity works very similarly. Nothing you do to the *groups* opacity will alter the internal *object(s)* opacity.

Comment: [I'm sorry but I just reproduced this, and you're wrong](https://imgur.com/a/kTcH5tq). Both objects with different specs are grouped, changing the stroke changes both of them. The "?" in the stroke before I change it is what should be in the "100%" Opacity setting...

Comment: True, but my point still stands, which is, *some* (arbitrary) specifics of elements within a group can be altered together - even though they *are* in a group (i.e. the stroke in my GIF), and *some* can't (i.e. the opacity in the original question). The way AI works is illogical and confusing. One should be able to change all opacity settings in a group if one can change stroke settings.

Comment: Okay @MicroMachine I'm actually going to **agree with you** here after specifically testing this (in CS6 anyway). Sometimes you do something so often for so many years you overlook nuances. You are correct that while other appearance items (stroke and fill settings specifically) *will* allow you to make "global" type of object adjustments to objects *within* a group. Opacity will *not* do the same thing. So, you're right. Opacity fails to follow the logic set forth by other appearance alterations. `:)`

Comment: Phew! Fun talking with you  Until next time...

Comment: I simply *never* set global stroke colors that way for grouped objects. So I failed to see the difference previously. Thanks for showing me something new `:)`

Comment: I will say that adjusting the opacity for a group in the *Appearance Panel* is exactly the same as adjusting Stroke and Fills *on groups* in the Appearance panel, though. :) So *technically* it's the *Transparency Panel* which fails to follow the same logic as the Stroke and Color Panels. If I have a Group selected on the artboard, the *Transparency* panel should read "---" if objects within the group have different opacity settings. Then if I were to choose an opacity setting on the Transparency Panel, *all* objects *within* the group should be set to that opacity -- there's where it breaks.

Comment: Sorry, just my nature to dig to find out the "why". `:)`

Comment: No, it's good to get to the bottom of things! I think many features of AI are just flawed, or badly designed, and AI groups definitely have an identity crisis! Are there groups to lock things in place, or to append modifications to several objects at once? Is a "group" an object with specific features of its own, or a metaphor for joined elements? Recently competitor apps have introduced *Joining*, *Parenting* to *Grouping* which helped make differences between them - but AI is slow to catch up...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89365/discussion-between-micromachine-and-scott).

Comment: AI is a behemoth with code that's more than 30 years old and it's been patched, and patched, and ported, and ported and patched again over the years. I don't disagree that it's got issues. From what I've gathered over the years, it's at that "too big to fix and remain financially viable" stage. Heck it was at that stage before the Creative Cloud junk... so it'll keep getting worse with every iteration. I'm honestly never surprised with a newer app does things better or more elegantly. Unless Adobe takes the time to rewrite *everything* ground up, it'll always have idiosyncrasies like this.

Comment: @MicroMachine Many 2D apps are lacking a whole deal when it comes to transformation stacks most competitors included. It would be much better if they really would expose the transformation with a much richer node like in 3D animation apps. But 2D users dont seem to know what they are  missing. Most DCC 3D apps are miles ahead of all 2D appsb ive used. The prloblem is that 2D apps seem to be stuck between being easy and having rich systems. 3D Apps almost universally fall into thr hard to use catyegory by default so they dont need to pretend

Comment: @joojaa true, 3D apps (which also let users create 2D graphics...) offer a ton more, some even for free, but mostly they kind of *have* to make sense - a lot of things don't make sense even within the Adobe apps interfaces to begin with. The framework of Adobe Apps, the way files are handled, the different panels across apps that actually perform the same actions, nothing is consistent when everything should be consistent (only bugs are consistent actually). I heard teams don't communicate, and when I have to go into InDesign to create vector elements for an AI file, I believe it...

Comment: @MicroMachine actually illustrator versions differ a bit if they are consistent or not. If you apply a stroke on a object then group it and apply a stroke to the group. Which appears to stroke each object, but in fact its a stroke on top of each objects stroke. Which is probably how its  äsupposed to work. But then they bactrack in next version so that this only happens if the stroke has been added in appearances panel. Then they go back and forh untill they settle with the version we have now.

Comment: The net result is that. In the quest to simplify interfaces they end up complicating the entire system on the whole. The system first appears simpler but is not. This has been going on for a long time, typical case example is the scale rotate handles of the selection tool. Which while common hides neccesary complexity from users. But at the same time makes the system more complex as now users skip the rotate and scale tools. This means users are now not aware that you can actually rotate,scale, skew and mirror about a specific point. Now they have increased complexity but users dint know it.